# AttributeError: 'CloudSchedulerClient' object has no attribute 'location_path'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I need to check current cloud-scheduler jobs in my project. And using these two snippets but I don't get why I am getting the error i.e.,

> {AttributeError: 'CloudSchedulerClient' object has no attribute 'location_path'}

And I have used seen this code from google cloud documentation.

```
from google.cloud.scheduler import CloudSchedulerClient

def display_cloud_scheduler(project):
  client = CloudSchedulerClient.from_service_account_json(
  r"./xxxx.json")
  print(client)
  parent = client.location_path(project, 'us-east1')
  for element in client.list_jobs(parent):
    print(element)
```

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1

def display_cloud_scheduler(project):
  client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient.from_service_account_json(
  r"./xxxx.json")
  print(client)
  parent = client.location_path(project, 'us-east1')
  for element in client.list_jobs(parent):
    print(element)
```

Does anyone have any idea, that what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what documentation you're following but the [official library docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudscheduler/latest/index.html) mention that the way you're doing is the ***old*** way and you should migrate to new method. This is explained in their [migration](https://googleapis.dev/python/cloudscheduler/latest/UPGRADING.html) guide:

> ### Before
>
> ```
> from google.cloud import scheduler
>
> client = scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient()
>
> parent = client.location_path("<PROJECT_ID>", "<LOCATION>")
> job = {
>        'app_engine_http_target': {
>            'app_engine_routing': {
>                'service': service_id
>            },
>            'relative_uri': '/log_payload',
>            'http_method': 'POST',
>            'body': 'Hello World'.encode()
>        },
>        'schedule': '* * * * *',
>        'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
>    }
>
> response = client.create_job(parent, job)
> ```
>
> ### After
>
> ```
> from google.cloud import scheduler
>
> client = scheduler.CloudSchedulerClient()
> parent = "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<LOCATION>"
> job = {
>        'app_engine_http_target': {
>            'app_engine_routing': {
>                'service': service_id
>            },
>            'relative_uri': '/log_payload',
>            'http_method': 'POST',
>            'body': 'Hello World'.encode()
>        },
>        'schedule': '* * * * *',
>        'time_zone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
>    }
>
> response = client.create_job(
>    request={
>        "parent": parent,
>        "job": job
>    }
> )
> ```

So I would suggest to to check your code and use the new methods. In addition in that migration guide it is mentioned the following about a migration script that could help to do those things easier:

> The script fixup_scheduler_{version}_keywords.py is shipped with the library. It expects an input directory (with the code to convert) and an empty destination directory.
>
> `$ fixup_scheduler_v1_keywords.py --input-directory .samples/ --output-directory samples/`